# No dropdownlist control in Visual Studio 2013 Desktop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a simple desktop app in Visual Studio 2013 Express Desktop. I want to drag and drop a dropdownlist and the bind it with database, but I cannot find the dropdownlist control in the toolbar. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it's called a Combo Box for desktop apps.

Comment: But when i use ComboBox1.DataBind()...it doesnt recognize the command.However,it works fine when i use dropdownlist in a web app.

Comment: use Combobox1.DataSource then set the displaymember and valuemember properties.